# Estimate an expression about probability about Bernoulli random variables

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Given $v_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$, $i \in \{1,2\}$, $j \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be random variables, $P[X_i=1]=P[X_i=0]=1/2$, $i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$. By checking many examples, I think that the following is true: when $|v_1|, |v_2|$ are large enough,
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_1=0}^n \sum_{x_2=0}^n | P[ \sum_{r=1}^n v_{1r}X_r = x_1, \sum_{r=1}^n v_{2r}X_r = x_2 ] - P[ \sum_{r=1}^n v_{1r}X_r = x_1+1, \sum_{r=1}^n v_{2r}X_r = x_2+1 ] | < 1-\epsilon. 
\end{align}
Is there some method to prove this? Thank you very much.

For example, let $n=4$, and $v_{1}=(v_{11},\ldots,v_{14})=(1,1,1,0), v_2=(v_{21},\ldots,v_{24})=(0,0,1,1)$, then the following Python codes gives the result $0.3446349999999999$.

```
import numpy as np

N = 10**5  

XX = [np.random.randint(2, size=4) for n in np.arange(N)]

r=0
for x1 in range(0,5):
    for x2 in range(0,5):
        P1 = list(map(lambda X: (X[0]+X[1]+X[2]==x1)&(X[2]+X[3]==x2), XX))
        P2 = list(map(lambda X: (X[0]+X[1]+X[2]==x1+1)&(X[2]+X[3]==x2+1), XX))
        r=r+abs(np.mean(P1)-np.mean(P2))
r/2
```

Let $n=4$, and $v_{1}=(v_{11},\ldots,v_{14})=(0,1,1,1), v_2=(v_{21},\ldots,v_{24})=(1,1,1,1)$, then the following Python codes gives the result $0.31340999999999997$.

```
import numpy as np

N = 10**5  

XX = [np.random.randint(2, size=4) for n in np.arange(N)]

r=0
for x1 in range(0,5): 
    for x2 in range(0,5):
        P1 = list(map(lambda X: (X[1]+X[2]+X[3]==x1)&(X[0]+X[1]+X[2]+X[3]==x2), XX))
        P2 = list(map(lambda X: (X[1]+X[2]+X[3]==x1+1)&(X[0]+X[1]+X[2]+X[3]==x2+1), XX))
        r=r+abs(np.mean(P1)-np.mean(P2))
r/2
```

Comment: Are the $X_i$'s independent?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis, thank you very much! Yes, the $X_i$'s are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shall assume that the $X_i$'s are independent. The problem can be restated as follows: show that for some $h\in(0,1)$, all natural $n$, and all subsets $J$ and $K$ of the set $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$
we have
\begin{equation*}
S:=\sum_{x,y}|P(X_J=x,X_K=y)-P(X_J=x+1,X_K=y+1)|\le2-h, \tag{1} 
\end{equation*}
where $X_J:=\sum_{i\in J}X_i$ and the sum in (1) is over all all integers $x,y$. Write
\begin{equation*}
    S\le T+U, \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
T:=\sum_{x,y}|P(X_J=x,X_K=y)-P(X_J=x+1,X_K=y)|,
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
U&:=\sum_{x,y}|P(X_J=x+1,X_K=y)-P(X_J=x+1,X_K=y+1)| \\  
&=\sum_{x,y}|P(X_J=x,X_K=y)-P(X_J=x,X_K=y+1)|.  
\end{align*}

By the independence of the $X_i$'s,
\begin{equation*}
    P(X_J=x,X_K=y)=\sum_z P(X_{J\cap K}=z)P(X_{J\setminus K}=x-z)P(X_{K\setminus J}=y-z). 
\end{equation*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
T&\le\sum_zP(X_{J\cap K}=z)\,\sum_y P(X_{K\setminus J}=y-z) \\ 
&\times\sum_x|P(X_{J\setminus K}=x-z)-P(X_{J\setminus K}=x+1-z)| \\ 
&=\sum_x|P(X_{J\setminus K}=x)-P(X_{J\setminus K}=x+1)|=:D_{|J\setminus K|}, 
\end{align*}
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality.
Similarly, $U\le D_{|K\setminus J|}$, so that, by (2)
\begin{equation*}
    S\le D_{|J\setminus K|}+D_{|K\setminus J|}. \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
Note that $D_0=1$ and, by [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/307506/36721), for $k\ge1$ we have
\begin{align*}
    D_k=\frac1{2^k}\,\Big(2\binom k{m+1}-1\Big)\le\frac34,  
\end{align*}
where $m:=\lfloor (k-1)/2\rfloor$. So, by (3),
\begin{equation*}
    S\le 1+3/4=7/4 
\end{equation*}
if $J\ne K$.

In the remaining case when $J=K$,
\begin{equation*}
S=\sum_x|P(X_J=x)-P(X_J=x+1)|=D_{|J|}\le1.  
\end{equation*}

Thus, in all cases (1) holds with $h=2-\max(7/4,1)=1/4>0$, as desired.

Comment: thank you very much for your great answer! I am trying to understand every step of your proof. In the formula before (3), it is said that $\sum_z P(X_{J \cap K}=z) \sum_y P(X_{K\backslash J}=y-z)=1$. I am trying to understand this step. I think that $$\sum_z P(X_{J \cap K}=z) \sum_y P(X_{K\backslash J}=y-z) \\=\sum_z P(X_{J \cap K}=z) \sum_y P(X_{K\backslash J}=y) = \sum_{y,z} P(X_{J \cap K}=z)  P(X_{K\backslash J}=y) \\=\sum_{y,z}P(X_{K}=y+z)=\sum_y P(X_{K}=y)=1$$. Is my understanding correct?  I checked that when $k=2$, $D_k=3/4$. So maybe for $k \ge 1$, $D_k \ge 3/4$?

Comment: sorry, I mean when $k \ge 1$, $D_k \le 3/4$.

Comment: @JianrongLi : Oops! I did indeed miss $3/4$; this is now corrected -- thank you for pointing this out. As for your detalization of the multi-line display before (3), what I had in mind was something like this, but a bit simpler: just using the fact that  $\sum\limits_t P(X_M=t)=1$.

Comment: thank you very much!